# Searching for encryption software for Windows from around year 2000, encrypting files in folders with names starting with @

Tags: windows, identify-this-software

I am searching for encryption software I was using around the year 2000, probably on Windows 2000. All I know is, it run at background and was automatically encrypting and decrypting files in folders with names starting with @. It asked for password and then all content read / written to these folders when accessed was encrypted on write or decrypted on read.

I don't know whether it was paid or free software.

I found some old CD backups with encrypted files I can not access now. I remember I was using this software but I can't remember its name :-(

Header of the encrypted files is in hex:

```
87 43 03 00 | 24 00 00 00 │ 1C 65 9C 52 │ 98 FA 4D 41 │ 52 54 49 4E
```

or in ascii:

```
WC..$....e.R..MARTIN
```

MARTIN is username. I can only guess "WC" was software name abbreviation. May be it was something like WinCrypt etc. but I had no luck finding the right software so far.

Are there people remembering old Windows days who could help me?